# Call a static method from CakePHP Plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, static, load

I have a class with a static method called hash from a plugin class called "ControllerUtility"

The function is located in ControllerUtility/Model/ControllerUtility.php

```
public static function hash( $string )
{
    return hash( 'sha256' , $string );
}
```

How do I call this method in a model or controller in a static way, I don't want to load this class into $this, since that will give me an instance of the object.

I want to call

```
ControllerUtility::hash( "string );
```

instead of changing the function to a non-static function and then calling

```
$this->ControllerUtility->hash( "string );`
```

in my controller

Comment: `I want to call ControllerUtility::hash( "string" );` - That's the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to include it using:

```
App::uses('ControllerUtility', 'ControllerUtility.Model');
```

And then you can call:

```
ControllerUtility::hash("string");
```